# How to format a booteable usb made by Startup Disk Creator

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, format, usb-creator

I've made a usb booteable to install ubuntu with Startup Disk Creator, I want restore it to normal state and delete all files inside. When I try to format my usb i get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Install mkusb

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe  

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mkusb
```

Run mkusb 
and select **restore to a standard storage device**

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution.

1. Open **Disks** from your dash
2. Select your pen drive

   I took this picture after deleting the partitions

   [image: Screenshot]

   there will be 3 partitions.
3. Format the 1st partition by clicking the **settings** icon
4. Delete the other 2 partitions by clicking the <kbd>-</kbd> (minus mark/dash)
5. After that, format the whole pen drive again.

This will fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Well I recommend to install GUI application **gparted** from the software center. Use this software to delete all the partitions you made in your USB and make it as a whole sole partition.

> Note: *GPARTED is a powerful application which requires root
>   privileges to operate, so while formating if you choose your hard disk partition
>   instead of USB for formating, then all your hard disk will be wiped off. So
>   use it carefully if you are new to it.*

Thats all.

Comment: The first one is locked http://oi68.tinypic.com/15gb385.jpg

Comment: Right click, unlock it and delete all partitions before making new ones. For faster and better results install and use MKUSB (wipe menu).

Comment: Your answer could be improved by including more detail about the steps needed to remove or overwrite a partition table on a USB memory stick that has been through the Make Bootable Disk process. The warning is a good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

So, you seem to have made partitions on your disk `:-)`
You just need to delete all partitions and make a single partition of the full disk. Then you can format that partition.

Use [How to Use Fdisk to Manage Partitions on Linux](http://www.howtogeek.com/106873/how-to-use-fdisk-to-manage-partitions-on-linux/).

`sudo fdisk -l` to list all the disks on your system and locate the USB
An easy way is to run this command w/o and then with your USB connected to the system.

`sudo fdisk /dev/sdX` -- where 'sdX' is replaced suitably to access your USB device.
Carefully select the correct drive at this point.

Use the `p` command to print the partitions on the disk.
Use the `d` command to delete all partitions one-by-one.
Use the `n` command to create a new single primary partition covering the entire free space.
You might also want to use the command `t` at this point to set the system ID to FAT16 (1) or `ext` etc.
Use the 'w` command to write this partition entry and exit.

---

Eek! I forget where we are!! Ignore this.
Check [How To Manage Partitions on Windows Without Downloading Any Other Software](http://www.howtogeek.com/101862/how-to-manage-partitions-on-windows-without-downloading-any-other-software/) for help.
One word of caution: be sure you are deleting partitions on your USB and not one of your hard drives.

Answer (score 0):

I got error like this and solved by exfat-utils.
install following file system using terminal

> sudo apt-get install exfat-utils exfat-fuse

After format usb drive

Comment: No, nothing to do with it. exfat* just provides support for the Microsoft proprietary exFAT file system, typical of 64GB+ flash drives. It has nothing to do with the reported problem .